# Why "Lasst" and not "Lassen"?

Tags: conjugation

In the following sentence, why is "Lasst" used instead of "Lassen"? For example, we say "wir lassen" so I thought that similarly we should use "Lassen uns" instead of "Lasst uns"?

> Lasst uns über diesen Punkt abstimmen.

Comment: The form used in polite salutation would be: *Lassen Sie uns über diesen Punkt abstimmen*.  Is that, what you are asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is imperative. One indication is that the verb is in the first position, not in the second.

Also, it is addressed to second person (du/ihr), not first person (ich/wir). An equivalent indicative sentence would be

> Ihr lasst uns über diesen Punkt abstimmen.